# How to change color of a single citation in a given beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, citing

I am using beamer for making slides. I want to change the color of both footnote mark and full citation in such a way that

1. First citation and mark appear red
2. Second citation and mark appear blue

Here is my MVE and snapshot of the output. I would appreciate if someone can suggest a solution preferably with \footfullcite{.}.

MVE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{precoderreferences}
\begin{document}
{
{\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\color{blue}{Main Slide (I)}}
\begin{itemize} 
\item ABC \footfullcite{Tuchler2002}
\item XYZ \footfullcite{Wu2003}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{precoderreferences}
\begin{document}
{
{\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\color{blue}{Main Slide (I)}}
\begin{itemize} 
\item ABC 
    {
        \setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=red}
        \setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}
        \footfullcite{Tuchler2002}
    }
\item XYZ \footfullcite{Wu2003}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]