# Stepwise show `\footfullcite`

Tags: beamer, citing, overlays

> The following Q&A is based on an answer I wanted to give for [How to change color of a single citation in a given beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301586/36296), but since a radical edit of the question, my answer does no longer fit, so I'm going to post it as a new question, in the hope it might be useful for someone else.

How to uncover `\footfullcite` step by step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the `\footfullcite` command in `\only`-environments gives the desired effect:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\makeatother
\def\insertcont{%
  \pgfmathparse{\insertpagenumber-\insertframestartpage+1}%
  (\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Main Slide \insertcont}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item ABC \only<2->{\footfullcite{Tuchler2002}}
            \item XYZ \only<3>{\footfullcite{Tuchler2002}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

To prevent the jumping of the first footnote between the slides, one can use the following little hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\makeatother
\def\insertcont{%
  \pgfmathparse{\insertpagenumber-\insertframestartpage+1}%
  (\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Main Slide \insertcont}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item ABC \only<2->{\footfullcite{Tuchler2002}}
                      \only<2>{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{~}}
            \item XYZ \only<3>{\footfullcite{Tuchler2002}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]